# How to lock out unauthorized users from application?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel 4 application which uses phpCAS single sign on to authenticate users. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to lock out any unauthorized users from accessing any of my application URLs. For this case, there are many users who would be able to pass the phpCAS log in page, but should at the same time be denied access to my application (except the Access Denied page) if they do not have admin rights.

How do I lockout these users from accessing my app's URLs while displaying my Access Denied page?

Routes.php:

```
Route::get('/adminHome/{USER_ID}', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'AdminController@home'));

Route::get('/adminHome/create/{USER_ID}', 'AdminController@create');

Route::get('/adminHome/{adminID}/delete/{USER_ID}', 'AdminController@delete');

Route::post('/adminHome/store/{USER_ID}', 'AdminController@store');

Route::get('/adminHome', 'AdminController@__construct');

Route::get('/accessDenied', array('as' => 'accessDenied', 'uses' => 'AdminController@accessDenied'));
```

Admin Controller:

```
public function __construct() 
{
    App::make('CAS');
    $ID = $_SESSION['phpCAS']['attributes']['UDC_IDENTIFIER'];
    $admin = App::make('AdminServices');
    $isValidAdmin = $admin->isAdmin($ID);
    //check DB to see if user has admin access rights
    if ($isValidAdmin && $isValidAdmin->ADMIN == "yes")
        {
            return Redirect::route('home', $ID);
        }
    else
        {   
            return Redirect::route('accessDenied');
        }

}

public function accessDenied()
{
    return View::make('users/accessdenied');
}
```

views/users/accessdenied:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" align="center"><strong>Access Denied. </strong>You do not have permission to access this page. Please notify the system administrator to obtain access.</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for [filters](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters)

Comment: your code seems already solve your problem

Comment: @MattBurrow, that was what I needed. Got it working now using filters.php

Answer (score 0):

put accessDenied into a single controller, then extends all of your other controllers from BaseController.e

BaseController could be

```
class BaseController extends Controller {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->beforeFilter('auth');
  }
}
```

then forget about it, it works fine.

and you can do anything you want in app/filters.php, `Route::filter('auth', function(){...});`